# Concatenating repeating String n times to themself basing on value from Collectors.groupingBy(K, V)

Tags: java, string, functional-programming, java-stream

Let's say that I have a method which is finding possible substrings in the `String` and return the particular one which will occur more than one time, otherwise, it's returning -1. For example for `abcdabcd` it returns `abcd`. My current solution is pretty close to the ideal, but I want to return instead of `abcd`, concatenated occurrence with result `abcdabcd` basing on `Collectors.groupingBy` value because according to the `Key : Value` pairs: `"abcd"` occurred twice.

```
public static String StringPeriods(String str) {

    List<String> substrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.length(); j++) {
        substrings.add(str.substring(i, j));
      }
    }

    return substrings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(stringLongEntry -> stringLongEntry.getValue() > 1)
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .//magic here
        .findFirst()
        .orElse("-1");
  }
```

Moreover, I would avoid reopening stream, instead of using `concat()` method or another simple solution. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to reach a goal.

Comment: can you share an input please?

Comment: So in your example, the end result of all that would be the original string again? Looks a bit pointless.

Comment: And what about ties? What is the intended result for `"ababxyxy"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem in multiple steps:

```
// Step 1: group by counting 
Map<String, Long> grouping = substrings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

// Step 2: find the max value    
Long maxValue = grouping.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .get()
        .getValue();

// Step 2: filter the entry which have max value and then max length, 
// In the end repeat your String maxValue time
return grouping.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == maxValue)
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)))
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey().repeat(maxValue.intValue()))
        .get();
```

I don't get you, when you use `orElse("-1")`, I think it is useless, just use `get()` in the end, and if you want to avoid empty strings, then just make a check in the start of your method:

```
if (str.isEmpty()) {
    return "-1";
}
```

Note: I used `repeat` which exist in Java11, if you are using an old version, there are many ways to repeat a string.

---

Or as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680166/concatenating-repeating-string-n-times-to-themself-basing-on-value-from-collecto/61680963?noredirect=1#comment109164051_61680963) mention, you in one shot use:

```
return substrings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().thenComparingInt(e -> e.getKey().length()))
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey().repeat(entry.getValue().intValue()))
        .get();
```